# Get an specific value in a multidimensional array from an API with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, multidimensional-array

I'm trying get the values of an array but the maximum I can do is

```
$characters = $array['data']['results'];
```

Why can't I go deeper in the array like doing `$characters['stories']` for example?

See picture as an example. So if I want to show in my page the name of the series, how can I bring this value? I know it's a beginner question. A colleague told me to use array_key_exists but in other answers in stackoverflow people suggest other things, is there an unique way or a more correct way to do that? By the way, I tried to adapt answers and it didn't work.

[Arrays with results from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmFFF.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the image, after `results` there's a property named `0`. In order to be able to get `stories`, you need to use:

```
$characters = $array['data']['results'];
$characters[0]['stories'];
```

If there are more numeric indices like that and you want to traverse each, you'll have to use a `for` or `foreach` loop.

**Example:** *(using `foreach`)*

```
foreach ($characters as $character) {
    # Print the stories array for each character.
    print_r($character['stories']);
}
```

**Example:** *(using `for`)*

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($characters); $index++) {
    # Print the stories array for each character.
    print_r($characters[$index]['stories']);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your first example say `print_r($character['stories']);` - I mean singular character?

Comment: Yes, thanks @uom-pgregorio. I answered this question from my phone and auto-correct did its thing again...

Comment: Thank you @angel-politis, it solved my problem, thanks for your help and explanation! :)